# Excel formula for converting time. yyyy-dd-mm hh-ii needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to convert time from `2/28/2013 21:46` (European 24h format) to `2013-02-28 21-46` (dash between hh-mm) using formula in Excel?
P.S. I didn't find such format in the `select cell->right click->format cell->date & time.`

I need this to rename a lot of .jpg files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so with a formula as follows, but it will also be converted to text and lose its numeric value:

```
=TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm")
```

You can use formatting via Right Click -> Format Cell, but if it's not in your regional settings, you will have to type `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm` under "Custom Format" instead of the "Date" format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it by reconstructing a string value (using A1 for the source):

```
=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,4)+1,4) & "-" & 
 IF(LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1))=1,"0","") &
 LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1) & "-" & 
 MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,FIND("/",A1,4)-FIND("/",A1)-1) & " " &
 MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(":",A1)-FIND(" ",A1)-1) & "-" &
 RIGHT(A1,2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Got it. However, the date should start from the year (the order should be changed).

Answer (score 0):

If you need this within the context of a VBA macro, then:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm"
End Sub
```